# Condensing data based on date range

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have data in the below format:

Vbeln repeats over a date range Begda and Endda. For Different Begda and Endda range PernrZa and PernrZb changes (however it may go back to previous state in a future date range. The date range is contiguous.

I need to condense the date range and build a contiguous date range

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   Vbeln                NVARCHAR(12)
   , Begda           NVARCHAR(10) -- but can be converted to datetime2
   , Endda           NVARCHAR(10) -- but can be converted to datetime2
   , PernrZa          NVARCHAR(10)
   , PernrZb         NVARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Data (Vbeln, Begda, Endda, PernrZa, PernrZb)
VALUES
('3000080085','19000101','20160411','1111111','1111111')
,('3000080085','20160412','20160418','1521708','1895971')
,('3000080085','20160419','20160516','1521708','1895971')
,('3000080085','20160517','20160519','1521708','1895971')
,('3000080085','20160520','20160523','1521708','1895971')
,('3000080085','20160524','20160606','1521708','2304882')
,('3000080085','20160607','20160628','1521708','1895971')
,('3000080085','20160629','20160826','1521708','2304882')
,('3000080085','20160827','20160909','1521708','2304882')
,('3000080085','20160910','20161011','1579311','2304882')
,('3000080085','20161012','20161201','1579311','2889814')
,('3000080085','20161202','20161225','1579311','2889814')
,('3000080085','20161226','99991231','1111111','1111111')
,('2000094798','19000101','20121029','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20121030','20121224','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20121225','20130331','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20130401','20131003','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20131004','20140429','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20140430','20150326','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20150327','20160826','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20160827','20160909','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20160910','20161201','1315393','1315393')
,('2000094798','20161202','99991231','1315393','1315393')
```

I want the output as below:

```
'3000080085','19000101','20160412','1111111','1111111'
'3000080085','20160412','20160524','1521708','1895971'
'3000080085','20160524','20160607','1521708','2304882'
'3000080085','20160607','20160629','1521708','1895971'
'3000080085','20160629','20160910','1521708','2304882'
'3000080085','20160910','20161012','1579311','2304882'
'3000080085','20161012','20161226','1579311','2889814'
'3000080085','20161226','99991231','1111111','1111111'
'2000094798','19000101','99991231','1315393','1315393'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the groups using `lag()`:

```
select vbeln, PernrZa, PernrZb, min(begda), max(endda)
from (select d.*,
             sum(case when prev_enda = dateadd(day, -1, begda) then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by vbeln, PernrZa, PernrZb order by begda) as grp
      from (select d.*,
                   lag(endda) over (partition by vbeln, PernrZa, PernrZb order by begda) as prev_enda             
            from #data d
           ) d
     ) d
group by vbeln, PernrZa, PernrZb, grp;
```

Note that this will give `enda` one day earlier -- because this is how the original data is structured.  You can add one to the end date, if you really so desire.

[Here](http://rextester.com/LSBRB70670) is a rextester.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. It didn't give the output that I wanted. For Vbeln 2000094798, I should only see one record where as for the other one I should see 8 rows each progressing from 1900 to 9999

Comment: @EnnSpace . . . Isn't that what the rextester does on the data you supplied?

Comment: If you take a look at the last record for 3000080085, it's wrong. The range for 1579311, 2889814 values should end by '20161226'. A new series should start for 1111111, 1111111 from 20161226
all the way through 99991231.

Comment: @EnnSpace . . . That is pretty much *exactly* what is in rextester.  The only difference is that the end date is one day earlier -- because it matches the data rather than adding an extra day.